# Word 2010 VBA - "Update Fields" changes font to Arial Narrow

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word

I have a macro which contains the line "Selection.Fields.Update" in order to go through the document and update all fields (to calculate some GST amounts that are in tables throughout the document).

The calculations happen as expected, however for some reason, the font is changed from Times New Roman 10 pt to Arial Narrow 10 pt (or sometimes 12 pt), and I cannot for the life of me work out why. After three days I am none the wiser as to why it is happening or how to get around it.

To clarify:

1. The fields are all in cells in a table so they can use cell referencing to perform calculations
2. The same thing occurs when doing the process manually, i.e. right click on the field and select "Update Field", so I believe this is not a code issue per se.
3. The same thing happens on another PC in my office (same SOE so not surprising)
4. Section of code that initiates the change is straightforward.

   ```
   ' Update all FIelds
   Selection.WholeStory
   Selection.Fields.Update
   Selection.WholeStory
   ```

I have confirmed the default font (TNR 10pt), as well as deleted the field(s) and re-created them.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to S.O.! Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I feel that your question could be good, however it doesn't provide the code required to investigate the issue. The question is too vague because it could be a number of things (your macro actually sets the font inadvertently, word glitch, another macro event runs on field updates)

Answer (score 0):

Closing this off as it doesn't belong here - the fact that it does the same thing under a manual process means it is not code related. Looking like a styles issue more than anything else so will head down that path